# Integrating CocoaLumberjack 2.2.0 version for Xcode 7.2

Tags: objective-c, logging, cocoalumberjack

I'm trying to integrate CocoaLumberjack 2.2.0 version in my project for which I'm using Xcode 7.2.
But, as per CocoaLumberjack's current version there is requirement of Xcode 8, they said that for backword compatibility use CocoaLumberjack 2.2.0 version for Xcode 7.2, but I'm not getting how to download CocoaLumberjack 2.2.0 version.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:  pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift', '2.2.0'

if that doesn't work try this : pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift', '~> 2.2.0'

Also have a look at this: https://cocoapods.org

Comment: Thanks Taha. I am done with this by doing **platform :ios, ‘7.0’** and **pod 'CocoaLumberjack', '~> 2.2.0’**